# Embedded-Task-Forms do not show the value of variable in Camunda 7.2.0-alpha5

Tags: java, business-process-management, bpmn, camunda

In the 7.2.0-alpha5 version of camunda-bpm I cannot see the value of the variable "complete". It only shows an empty textfield. It's working in 7.1.0-final. Did the way of addressing a variable change in 7.2.0?

Thats what it looks like in tasklist:

[image: tasklist-view]

I guess my variable is correctly initialized at least according to cockpit:

[image: variable in cockpit]

Below is the code of my embedded-task form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Task Complete?</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input form-field type="boolean" name="complete" readonly="true"/>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs of the camunda BPM JS SDK](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-sdk-js/blob/master/doc/embedded-forms/controls/inputs.md#boolean) your input HTML should rather look like:

```
<input type="text"
   cam-variable-name="complete"
   cam-variable-type="Boolean" />
```

In HTML, there's no `type="boolean"`, the 'equivalent' would rather be a `type="checkbox"` (but [it still has to be implemented](https://app.camunda.com/jira/browse/CAM-2499))

Comment: OK it seems to fix the issue. Thank you. I didnt even know that there is a camunda sdk-js. I guess they need to work some more on their documentation.

Comment: We are working on it. Actually, that SDK is, kind of, part of the upcoming (7.2) release. It is one of the angle stone of the new Tasklist app.